# Passing by const reference from a object member. IE someObject.function()

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Okay, I'm getting rusty or I just never noticed this before. I apologize in advance if this has been asked before, but I could not find anything related to what I'm asking, or I was searching the wrong key word. So Let me get to the point. when passing from a const referenced value from a function IE, the return type is a const reference of a member variable of type vector, I can't seem to use the value. Maybe I'm just super rusty, been programming in PHP and Javascript so I've been away from strong typing for a minute.

However, Let me show you some code to establish what I'm talking about.

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
class VectorTest
{
   public:

    VectorTest() 
    {

        std::string test = "";

        for (char letter = 'a'; letter < 'Z'; letter++)
        {
            test.push_back(letter);
            valueToReturn_.push_back(test);
        }

     }

     const std::vector<std::string>& ReturnByConstReference()
     {
         return valueToReturn_;
     }

    ~VectorTest() {}

  private:

    std::vector<std::string> valueToReturn_;

};
```

The above is the Vector test class for simplicity. now for the calling section

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include "VectorTest.h"

 void functionTest(const VectorTest* testItem)
 {
     std::vector<std::string> test((*testItem).ReturnByConstReference);
 }

 void functionTest(const VectorTest& testItem)
 {
     std::vector<std::string> test(testItem.ReturnByConstReference());
 }

 int main() 
 {

     VectorTest testVectorObject;

     //this works however the passing to the functions does not.
     std::vector<std::string> test(testVectorObject.ReturnByConstReference());

     functionTest(&testVectorObject);
     functionTest2(testVectorObject);

 }
```

Okay, so I can not figure out why the copy constructor for vector works in main, but if I pass the object VectorTest to the function as a const reference the compiler immediately throws a fit. I know I'm forgetting some rule about passing an object as a reference and then trying to access a function that passes back a private member variable as a const reference so I can avoid the cost of a copy.

This is of course a small scale version of what I'm trying to do, so I understand in this example a copy would not be that expensive.

I'm sure I'm forgetting something as to why this isn't working and how to get it to work, so if someone can refresh my memory I would greatly appreciate it.

Sorry again if this is something that has been asked before, but I'm not sure what term to enter for a search so I could not find my answer. Also sorry for any indention problems, copying from Visual studio to here is a bit annoying.

Also to reiterate, the copy constructor works in main, it's when I pass the object to the included functions, that everything goes side ways. Thank you again for your help, and if anything doesn't make sense let me know.

Comment: The method `ReturnByConstReference` is not marked `const` after the last parenthesis so it cannot be called on const references or const pointers.

Comment: holy crap! I can't believe I forgot something that simple. I know it was something simple I was over looking. In my mind it was playing as, can't use it to assign to a const value. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: That fixed the issue, I swear only the small things screw me up. If you want to post that answer, I'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters say `const VectorTest` but `ReturnByConstReference` is not `const`.

It would fail in `main` as well if you declared `const VectorTest testVectorObject;`

Make the function `const`:

```
const std::vector<std::string>& ReturnByConstReference() const
```

Comment: Yep, made the comment above that it was something super simple. Can't believe I over looked that.

Comment: Thanks for your help! it's the simple stuff that screws me up.